# JavaFx TreeCell how to expand nodes after one second

Tags: javafx, nodes, expand, treecell

i'm implementing the Drag&Drop on a generic TreeView.
My purpose is to expand a folder during DragEntered event after a second of stationing, actual code:

```
setOnDragEntered(e -> {
    TreeItem<TreeItemContent> enteredItem = getSourceItem(e);
    if(model.isFolder(enteredItem)){
       enteredItem.setGraphic(images.getFolderOpened());
       enteredItem.setExpanded(true);
    }
    e.consume();
});
```

desired:

```
setOnDragEntered(e -> {
    TreeItem<TreeItemContent> enteredItem = getSourceItem(e);
    if(model.isFolder(enteredItem)){
       if(dragDuration >= 1 sec){
          enteredItem.setGraphic(images.getFolderOpened());
          enteredItem.setExpanded(true);
       }
    }
    e.consume();
});
```

There is a standard resolution for this scope ? or i must implement this function by myself ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [PauseTransition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html) for adding the delay. On its `setOnFinished()`, you can add an action to be performed after the supplied time has elapsed.

On `setOnDragEntered()`, you can start the `PauseTransition` and on `setOnDragExited()`, check the `status` of `PauseTransition` and if it is still in `RUNNING` status, `stop` it.

Here is a simple code, which uses, `setOnMouseEntered()` and `setOnMouseExited()`, instead of the above two mentioned events, on a `Button`. But, this should be more than enough to give you an idea.

**Code :**

```
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
}

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Label label = new Label("Hi");

        Button button = new Button("Add");
        PauseTransition pt = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(1000));

        pt.setOnFinished( ( ActionEvent event ) -> {
            label.setText(String.valueOf("Done!"));
        });

        button.setOnMouseEntered(event -> {
            pt.play();
        });

        button.setOnMouseExited(event -> {
            if(pt.getStatus() == Animation.Status.RUNNING) {
                pt.stop();
                label.setText("Interrupted");
            }
        });

        VBox box = new VBox(20, label, button);
        box.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(box, 200, 200);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Welcome");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: in this way the action takes place after a second regardless of how the user stations on that node

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a standard solution for this issue, but i have resolved with a custom implementation:

```
setOnDragEntered(e -> {
    TreeItem<TreeItemContent> enteredItem = getSourceItem(e);
    model.setEnteredItem(enteredItem);
    if(model.isFolder(enteredItem)){
       new Thread(()->{
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                if(enteredItem == model.getEnteredItem()){
                    enteredItem.setGraphic(images.getFolderOpened());
                    enteredItem.setExpanded(true);
                }
            } catch (Exception e1) {}
       }).start();
    }
}
```

In this way i can compare the first enteredItem with the enteredItem that i have after a second.

For completeness:

```
private TreeItem<TreeItemContent> getSourceItem(InputEvent e){
   return ((TreeCell)e.getSource()).getTreeItem();
}
```